# Russian words translated into IPA

Tags: перевод

I would need your constructive expert opinion on my IPA translations. This is a difficult topic so bare with me.

Желтéть         ʐɛltʲetʲ

чернéет         t͡ɕɪɾˈnʲeɛt

с детьми        s ͡ ˈdʲetʲmɪ

Аквалáнг        ɐkvɐˈlank

Жёлудь - Жора   ˈʐolʊtʲ - ˈʐorə

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- ʐᵻlˈtʲetʲ
- t͡ɕɪrˈnʲeɪt — two things here: 1. /r/ is definitely a trill in this position; 2. AFAIK, most or all authorities would insist on [t͡ɕɪrˈnʲejɪt], but I daresay the [j] is a bit of an academic relic; no-one really ever articulates it.
- z‿dʲɪtʲˈmʲi (it's got mobile stress)
- the rest are OK.

P.S. It took some time to find, but [this](http://easypronunciation.com/en/russian-phonetic-transcription-converter) seems to be an automated Russian IPA transcriptor that works. (Sadly it seems to never stop asking for the math captcha.)